# How to pass model (and anything else) from view to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

The overload for @Html.Partial takes a model, so in the "primary" view I put in this.model:

```
@Html.Partial("_GenericIndex", this.Model )
```

I tried just putting @Model in the partial view to see if anything showed up, but I got nothing.

So, how do I use that this.Model parameter in the partial view? I have seen some horrible solutions where it was prepared especially for the partial view in viewdata or something. Surely that is not necessary?

**I just want to access the Html.Partial argument that I enter into it**.

By the way my controller and action are like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    IRepository<Customer> customerrepo = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<Customer>();

    //
    // GET: /Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Customer cust = customerrepo.GetByID("1");
        return View(cust);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arg, it didnt help me in this test that all this time there was no customer with ID "1" in the database...

Comment: Thanks people, I have a better understanding of the system now. Since I am trying to make a generic view I ended up using ViewBag to pass a model dynamically. I also added the chosen model's modelmetadata to the ViewBag by calling this in my generic controller action: ModelMetadata entitymetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => item, typeof(T));

Comment: Update: I am switching to using a dynamic model in order to work toward getting a generic view going:                                                           IList<T> list = Repository.GetAll();
                dynamic model = list;
                return View(model);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply this line to the top of your partial view:

```
@model Customer
```

Then you can use `@Model` in your partial view, and it will represent the object you passed in your `@Html.Partial("_GenericIndex", Model)` call.
even you can call @Html.Partial("_GenericIndex"), which will passon the model of the current page to the partial page.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the model type in your partial view?

```
@{
    var model = ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as Customer;
}
```

Comment: Still trying it, but this approach might be good because I am trying to make a generic partial.